# How to check that two propery in an object have the same value

Tags: node.js, jasmine-node

I use the test framework Frisby and I want to check that two propery have the same value as in the exampel below where count must be equal to total_count.
I have been looking around but haven't any way to check that two property have
the same value.

Here is the code that I use to validate the GET.The call to the API list all the users that are registered in the system.

```
frisby.create('GET Method')
          .get(urlMultiNetworkAdminUser)
          .expectStatus(200)
          .expectJSON({

          })
          .expectJSONTypes({
              rows : Array,
              count : String,
              total_count : String
          })
          .expectJSONTypes('rows.*' ,{
              id : Number,
              setting_group_id: function(val) { expect(val).toBeTypeOrNull(Number); },
              login : String,
              email : String,
              language_code : String,
              role : String,
              ismultinetworkadmin : Boolean,
              real_name : String,
              subscribe_to_issues : Boolean,
              external_account : Boolean,
              href : String
          }).toss();

{
    "rows":
    [
        {
          "id":109,
          "setting_group_id":null,
          "login":"Admin",
          "email":"dise.server@dise.com",
          "language_code":"en",
          "role":"user",
          "ismultinetworkadmin":false,
          "real_name":"Amin",
          "subscribe_to_issues":false,
          "external_account":false,
          "href":"/api/v1/users/109"
        },
        {
           "id":110,
           "setting_group_id":null,
           "login":"User",
           "email":"dise.server@dise.com",
           "language_code":"en",
           "role":"user",
           "ismultinetworkadmin":false,
           "real_name":"User",
           "subscribe_to_issues":false,
           "external_account":false,
           "href":"/api/v1/users/110"
        }
    ],
    "count":"2",
    "total_count":"2"
}
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

to check deep equality - which i think is what you want to do - use underscore ...

```
expect(_.isEqual(actual, expected)).toBe(true);
```

you could also use lodash or write your own function to check for deep equality.